# Align Bootstrap glyphicons vertically with text on both sides?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
usernad <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ape<br>
dads <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> stack<br>
defdood <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> rocks<br>
eleminem <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> boom<br>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
te43st@gmail.com <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> tester32<br>
te44st@gmail.com <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> fourteenppl<br>
test32@gmail.com <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> eleven<br>
test@gmail.com <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> goo<br>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create two columns, each with rows in this format: `text glyphicon text`, but I want to align the glyphicons vertically in the straight line for readability. Is there any way to do this with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to wrap the text with `span` then `float` it, and clear it at each 4 item. And you need to use `min-width`

> Right align text before the glyphicon is what I meant to say.

Then use `text-align:right`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dotted 1px red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px
}
div span {
  float: left
}
div span:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
  text-align: right
}
div:first-of-type span:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  min-width: 70px;
}
div:last-of-type span:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  min-width: 120px
}
.glyphicon {
  margin: 2px 5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <span> usernad</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span> ape </span>
  <span>dads</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  <span>stack</span>
  <span>defdood</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  <span>rocks</span>
  <span>eleminem </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span> boom</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span> te43st@gmail.com</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  <span>tester32</span>
  <span>te44st@gmail.com</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><span>fourteenppl</span>
  <span>test32@gmail.com</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  <span>eleven</span>
  <span>test@gmail.com</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  <span>goo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but I need the left side to be aligned with the left side of the glyphicon too.

Comment: can't understand what you need, sorry. you need the left column to have less whitespace? just reduce the min-width then. I can updated the answer for that

Comment: Right align text before the glyphicon is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with native bootstrap, but if you make your icon span inline-block you can then apply vertical-align to it (i've used top in the sample)

```
div {
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:32px;
}
span.glyphicon
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

I've made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywbg00am/) showing the alignment; I've also increased the line height to illustrate visually.

Comment: Not what OP is looking for